# i have code it can be sum two textbox values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sum

i have code it can be sum two textbox values using javascript but problem is that when i entered amount into `recamt` textbox value and javascript count again and again `recamt` textbox values it should be count only one time `recamt` textbox value not again and again?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function B(){
document.getElementById('advance').value
=(parseFloat(document.getElementById('advance').value))+
(parseFloat(document.getElementById('recamt').value));
return false;
}  
</script>

<input class="input_field2" type="text" readonly name="advance" 
id="advance" value="50" onfocus="return B(0);" /><br />
<input class="input_field2" type="text" name="recamt" id="recamt">
```

Comment: Where are you showing the result?

Comment: You're adding the value to the same element that you are retrieving the value from, so of course it just keeps on adding. Consider using a third input for the total value.

Comment: @ophintor it is count recamt textbox values again and again when ever i focus on advance textbox

Comment: @adeneo i don't want to use another textbox

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a property on the read-only text field to keep the old value:

```
function B()
{
    var adv = document.getElementById('advance'),
    rec = document.getElementById('recamt');

    if (typeof adv.oldvalue === 'undefined') {
        adv.oldvalue = parseFloat(adv.value); // keep old value
    }

    adv.value = adv.oldvalue + parseFloat(rec.value));
    rec.value = '';

    return false;
}
```

Comment: what about if you want to automactially clear recamt textbox values once recamt textbox values sum with advance textbox value?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the sum function every time the readonly input is focused using the new value. If you only want it to add to the original value, you need to store it somewhere.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="advance" readonly="readonly" value="50" /><br />
<input type="text" id="recamt">
```

JS:

```
var advanceBox = document.getElementById('advance');
var originalValue = advanceBox.value;

advanceBox.onclick = function() {
    this.value = parseFloat(originalValue) +
        parseFloat(document.getElementById('recamt').value);

    return false;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hQbhq/

Notes:

- You should bind your handlers in javascript, not HTML.
- The javascript would need to exist *after* the HTML on the page, or inside of a window.load handler, otherwise it will not be able to find `advanceBox`.

Comment: And you're sure you are not mixing parseFloat and parseInt in regards to the radix, as parseFloat does'nt have a radix ?